# C++ Class Typedef Struct does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make use of typedef structs inside of my C++ program. I started writing the following code until I received an error when trying to add a method to my class that returns a template typedef struct pointer.

StructSource.h

```
template <typename T>
class StructSource {
public:
    struct TestStruct{
        T value;
    };
};
```

User.h

```
#include "StructSource.h"

class User {
    public:
        typedef StructSource<int>::TestStruct IntStruct;

        IntStruct *getIntStruct();

};
```

User.cpp

```
#include "User.h"

IntStruct *User::getIntStruct() {
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error when compiling with GCC.

> User.cpp:3:1: error: ‘IntStruct’ does not name a type

I'm at a loss to explain why this is the case. What type information am I missing?

Comment: Quick answer while I'm looking for the duplicated question: Use `User::IntStruct`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"User" is also a "namespace" (scope, actually, as most commenters point out - "namespace" was for a quick answer) here, so you have to use

```
User::IntStruct *User::getIntStruct() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not a namespace, it's a *scope*. And you only have to use it because the return type is not inside the class scope, while the rest of the declaration / definition is. In fact, even a late-specified return type (C++11) is inside the class scope: `auto User::getIntStruct() -> IntStruct*{ return 0; }`.

Comment: of course, that's why I called it "namespace" in quotes. "Scope" also makes confusion with the run-time stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
User::IntStruct *User::getIntStruct() { ... }
```

IntStruct is defined inside the `User` scope, but the return value of the function is not in scope. there is a discussion of these scoping issues [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list).

Answer (score 2):

Since `IntStruct` was defined within the class, you must use the class name to reference it, except within the class code where it is part of the default name search path.

```
User::IntStruct *User::getIntStruct() {
```

This is *not* the same as a namespace, even though the syntax is identical.